# Change label text every two seconds and wait executing following cos

Tags: javascript, html

i need some code to change label text every two seconds for example on page load label text is "100" after two seconds is"200" after two more seconds is "300" and ....
i have an array for this meaning,my code is like this:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
    function func_code() {
        var codes = null;
        var code_arr = null;
        var j = null;
        var i = null;
        codes = "100000,100004,100007,100009,100012";
        code_arr = codes.split(',');
        var len = code_arr.length;
        for (j = 0; j <= len; j++) {
            for (i = code_arr[j]; i <= code_arr[j + 1]; i++) {
                setTimeout(function () { change_number(i) }, 2000);
              ******wait here for 2 seconds*******
            }
        }
               // document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 5000000;
    }
    function change_number(i) {
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = i;
    }

</script>
<label id="counter">123</label>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` is asynchronous. your 2 loops just run in a blink and set all those timeouts which just fire simultaneously after 2 seconds.

Comment: You need to wrap the `setTimeout` round the function.  The `i` value is read after the interval, not when set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understood correctly..

Maybe you need something like this?

```js
function func_code() {
    var codes = "100000,100004,100007,100009,100012";
    var code_arr = codes.split(',');
    for (i = 0;i < code_arr.length;i++) {
        (function(i){
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                change_number(code_arr[i]);
            }, 2000*i);
        })(i)
    }
}
                  
function change_number(i) {
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = i;
}

func_code();
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Comment: can anyone explain this part of code which wrapped in for loop,specially function(i) at the beginning  and (i) in end of this this function

Comment: It is the syntax to pass variables to a self invoked function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 setInterval(function () { change_number() }, 2000); 
 function change_number(){
     var elem = document.getElementById('counter');
     var val = elem.innerHTML;
     elem.innerHTML  = parseInt(val)+100;
 }
</script>
<label id="counter">100</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 100;
var myCounter = setInterval(function(){ 
console.log(x);
x = x+100;
if(x == 110){
clearInterval(myCounter); //to clear interval
}
 }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution would look something like this:

```
   var len = code_arr.length;
   function looper(j,len) {
        if (j<=len) {
            for (i = code_arr[j]; i <= code_arr[j + 1]; i++) {
                setTimeout(function () { 
                    change_number(i);
                    looper(j+1,len); // call the function again
                }, 2000);
            } // for
        } // if
    } // function
    looper(0,len);
```

Comment: thank you but this code show numbers like this:100008,100010,100013,100012,i don't know why